# RxJava2 - How to retry everytime except if it's TimeoutException?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I've got a chain of `Observables` and at the end of it, I'm writing a command to the device via Bluetooth and I'm waiting for the notification. There's a case, where it can wait here forever so I would like to use `timeout` - easy.

But the problem is that, I want to `retry` every time any other problem occurred, it should be terminated only if `timeout` happen - otherwise it should `retry`. Also, if we go down through the chain, we will meet other retries that also should have the same behavior. Timeout exception should be pushed back to the higher layer(interactor in my case).

I thought about `retryWhen` but I'm not sure how to use it properly in that case.

```
.retryWhen { it.filter { throwable -> throwable !is TimeoutException } }
```

Also, it's hard to write tests for that so it makes it harder for me to find the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this following approach which i am using for my project.

Create a class (It is a java class you can change it into kotlin if required)

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements Function<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {
private static final String TAG = "RetryWithDelay";

private final int maxRetries;
private final int retryDelayInMinutes;
private int retryCount;



public RetryWithDelay(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayInMinutes) {
    this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    this.retryDelayInMinutes = retryDelayInMinutes;
    this.retryCount = 0;
}

@Override
public Observable<?> apply(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
    return attempts.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> apply(Throwable throwable) {
            if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }

            if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                return Observable.timer(retryDelayInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }

            // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    });
}}
```

Inside apply method, it will check if the exception is instance of TimeOut , it will throw an error else it will keep retrying for the maxRetries you want.

And pass this class as below

```
  .retryWhen (new RetyWithDelay(3,5))
```

Where it will retry for 3 times every 5 mins.

Comment: @Denathan Happy to know it helped